# Receiving data from HTTP GET Request before redirecting to another page through a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to receive data from HTTP GET request and store it in a PHP variable before redirecting to another page. Here is the code.

```
    <?php 
session_start(); 
require("dbconfig.php");
?>
</html>
<head>
<a href="https://www.google.com/" class="btn btn-success" id="link" type="button" >Click me</a> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    jscounter=1;
    jscounter++;
    document.getElementById("link").onclick = function () {
        alert("javascript counter variable is " +jscounter);                                                                                                
        window.location = "?js_var=" + jscounter;
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>

<?php                       

if (isset($_GET['js_var'])) {
    $counter = $_GET['js_var'];
    echo "PHP counter variable is ".$counter;
    $squery = "update mycounter set counter=$counter";
    if(mysqli_query($dbc, $squery)) {        
        echo "Counter added to db successfully to DB"; 
    }
    else {
        echo mysqli_error($dbc);
    }  
}
?>                                            

</html>
```

The above code works when no link is mentioned in the hyperlink i.e., as below.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="link" type="button" >Click me</a>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is any problem with your code, you also don't mention one. Can you elaborate on what doesn't work here?

Comment: fyi - it is not valid to echo any content ( using PHP or otherwise ) between the closing body and closing html tags as above - nor is it valid to have an `a` element in the head section..

Comment: Another thing to be aware of here is that you update the db with the value held in the querystring ( ie: js_var=X ) - nothing to stop people entering an arbitary number. In addition the above sql is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: You can use `ajax` to update value of counter in `database` and on ajax `success` function you can redirect to the required page which is defined in `a` tag.

Comment: @Luca Kiebel. Sorry I missed to mention URL in href. I have edited my code now. Please run the code now. It will not receive data from HTTP GET request before it redirects to google.com.

Comment: What do you want to do with the value? right now it will always get set to `2`.

Comment: @Luca Kiebel. This is a sample code. In the real time, I am getting the $counter value from the database and assign it to jscounter and increase it by one.  Now I want my sample code to assign jscounter value to $counter before it redirects to google.com.

Comment: Do you always just want to increment it by one?

Comment: @Luca Kiebel. Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave your `<a href>` code as it is. When you're done getting your data and saving it.
Just redirect to desired page as :

```
header('Location: http://your.desired.link/');
```